# How to compare all the cells of DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, cells

I'm a C# beginner. Can you pl help how to compare all the cells of a DataGridView Column i.e. how to check if all the cells (of a Column) are of equal value. **I would like to do this EFFICIENTLY.**

Pl let me know the code as I do not want to do many iterations looping through DataGridView.

I've tried the one below:

```
bool *functionname()*
{
List<String> list_of_cellValues = new List<String>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow eachRow in BKCdataGrid.Rows)
            {
                String cellValue = eachRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                if (cellValue!= " " && cellValue!=null)
                    list_of_cellValues.Add(cellValue);
                else
                    continue;
            }
            return (list_of_cellValues.Distinct().Count() == 1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
    List<DataGridViewCell> l = new List<DataGridViewCell>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells.Count; h++)
        {
            l.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[h]);
        }
    }
    bool result = (l.Distinct().Count() == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if previous row has different value in Cell. If it does, return false.

```
bool functionname()
{
    if (BKCdataGrid.RowCount == 0)
    {
        return false;  // or true? Your call 
    }
    // Get cell value in first row
    object oldValue = BKCdataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;
    for (int i = 1; i < BKCdataGrid.RowCount; ++i)
    {
        if (BKCdataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != oldValue)
        {
            return false; // they are some differences
        }
    }
    // All cells are the same as the one in first row
    return true;
}
```

You should expand this function to accept column name as a parameter to improve reusability. An overload accepting column index would also come in handy.